# Perl DBI - Use of uninitialized value

Tags: database, perl, hashtable

SO.

I'm querying an Oracle database from a Perl script using Perl's DBI. I fetch the returned rows using the fetchrow_hashref (since I'll need the column name later). I put each of the returned rows into an array and I return a reference to that array. So basically I'm returning a reference to an array of references to hashes. Something like this:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute();

# Fetch all rows returned as hash references and put each of those
# references into the array @rows
@returned_rows = ();
while ($row =  $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
    push(@returned_rows, $row);
}

# Return a reference to the array @rows
# Return a reference to an array of hash references
return \@returned_rows;
```

If one of the fields comes as null, i get:

```
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at sqlesl.pl line 49.
```

Which is OK because I was expecting null values from the database, but even if I test for undef, I get the same error which makes me think things are not exactly as the DBI docs say they should be:

> An alternative to fetchrow_arrayref. Fetches the next row of data and
>   returns it as a reference to a hash containing field name and field
>   value pairs. Null fields are returned as undef values in the hash.

This is the piece of code I've been using to test the snippet above. Let's say *$rows_ref* is what the snippet above returns.

```
@rows = @$rows_ref;
$hash_ref = $rows[0];
%hash = %$hash_ref;
@keys = keys %hash;

foreach $key (@keys) {
    next if (undef($hash{$key}));
    print "$key: $hash{$key}\n";
}
```

Does someone have some light to shed on this one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that you can call `$sth->fetchall_arrayref({})` to get an arrayref of hashref rows, so you don't need to populate `@returned_rows` yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`undef` is the function which undefines its argument. In conditions, you should use `defined` instead:

```
next unless defined $hash{$key};
```

Comment: @horhay might also consider `exists $hash{$key}`

Comment: Both of you, thanks a lot! Both solutions are just what I needed.